# Exclude subfolder from Get-Childitem when comparing two folders

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a script that compares the content of two folders.

```
$var1 = Get-ChildItem -path C:\folder\ -Recurse -Name 
$var2= Get-ChildItem -path C:\folder18.0\ -Recurse -Name  
(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $var1-DifferenceObject $var2 |
ForEach-Object {
    $_.SideIndicator = $_.SideIndicator -replace '=>','Not in folder' -replace '<=','Not in 18.0'
    $_
})
```

Both directories have several subfolders and there are a few subfolders, with the same name, that I would like to exclude from the comparison. I have tried  applying `-exclude` and variants of `Where-Object -notcontain` to the first two lines but that doesn't seem to work. I feel like I'm on the right path but am not sure if I am applying it correctly. I'm still new to powershell so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe related https://superuser.com/questions/663186/cant-exclude-a-directory-pattern-recursively

Comment: Yep, not an exact dupe but that question has an answer that shows how you would exclude a subfolder when getting the lists.

Comment: Okay. This was a much simpler and cleaner solution than what I could find in my searches. Thanks!

Edit: I applied `Where {$_.FullName -notlike "*\subfolder\*"}` to the end of where I define `var1` and `var2` and I don't notice any changes when I run it.